# scrapy list command can see spider but runspider cant find it?

Tags: scrapy

If i type in

```
scrapy list
```

I get the correct answer which is a single spider i made called

```
wiki
```

but (staying in the same dir in cmd line) when i do;

```
scrapy runspider wiki
```

i get;

```
    2020-02-19 18:58:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: wikipedia)
2020-02-19 18:58:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: File not found: wiki
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `scrapy crawl`. `scrapy runspider` requires the file of your spider as argument.

`scrapy runspider <spider_file.py>`

`scrapy crawl <spider>`

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html

Comment: Thank you JEROEN E very much appreciated!